# Optimization by Sandy-Bridge CPU?

Tags: java, performance, cpu

I wrote the following Java test

```
public class NegativeTest {

/**
 * @param args
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {

    long start = System.currentTimeMillis();

    int value = 12345;
    for (int j = 0; j < 30; j++) {
        for (int i = 0; i < 1000000000; i++) {
            value = value * -1 - i;
        }
    }

    System.out.println(System.currentTimeMillis() - start);

    //to avoid compilation optimization
    System.out.println(value);
}
}
```

It took about **1.3 second** to finish on my Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-3210M (Ivy-Bridge) machine, however after I changed the line

**value = value * -1 - i**

to

**value = value - i**,

then it took about **10 sencond** to finish (about 10 times as long as the previous version)!

When I ran this test on other non-Sandy Bridge CPUs, the result is completely reversed:
the **value = value * -1 - i**  version takes twice as long the **value = value - i** version does!

Can anyone explain this difference? Is it related to any specific optimization design in Sandy Bridge architecture??

Comment: Well that's interesting. When I try this in C++, I get 0 seconds for the first case and 7.472 seconds for the second. It seems that in the first case, my C++ compiler manages to completely optimize the loop into a single value. So this basically boils down to compiler optimization. Perhaps the Java JIT is doing something different for SB. (oh and I tested it on a Sandy Bridge machine)

Comment: @Mysticial Did you try that on a non-sandy bridge machine?

Comment: It wouldn't matter. Because my C++ compiler optimized the first case to essentially `print("-2115085767")`. That would run in zero time on any processor.

Comment: In order to be sure that the issue is the presence or absence of the CPU, you would have to make sure other software components of the systems are identical.  For example, do both machines have: Same jdk version and bit depth(32/64)?  Same JVM version and bit depth?  Same operating system?  Both the java compiler and the JVM can play a role in the exact path that the system takes in order to solve this problem.  As we've seen, a certain C++ compiler actually solves the problem and just outputs a program that prints the answer!

Comment: If you are not using exactly the same version of Java, this can make more of a difference than the architecture of the system. BTW since your code doesn't do anything useful, it is quite likely that a future version of Java will eliminate it completely.

Comment: `value = value * -1 - i` is the same as `value = -value - i` which is not the same as `value = value - i`;

Comment: If I have a `long value` instead of an `int value` the timings are almost the same.  I suspect the difference is how much the JIT can optimise away the code.

Comment: todays actual CPUs are so powerful, that you only need a good algorithm, not a good implementation as compiler/CPU will manage it.

Answer (score 1):

I did try the same on C# .Net 4.6 x64

1) 16239ms

2) 8175ms

now if I look the disassembly diff:

1)

```
value = value * -1 - i;
000007FE9958422A  neg         edx  
000007FE9958422C  sub         edx,eax
```

2)

```
value = value - i;
000007FE995842A2  sub         edi,eax
```

I have an i7 4790K.

If I use double/float instead of integer the disassembly contains scalar AVX code, which could be faster:

```
value = value * -1 - i;
000007FE9957422B  vmulsd      xmm0,xmm0,mmword ptr [7FE99574298h]  
000007FE99574234  vcvtsi2sd   xmm1,xmm1,eax  
000007FE99574239  vsubsd      xmm0,xmm0,xmm1
```

So now it would be funny to use AVX 2.0 for integer.

Edit:

> When I try this in C++, I get 0 seconds

actually this is trolling :)

Please be advised benchmarking is not easy, you need to carefully look of disassembly, use precise counters, ensure CPU is not in balanced energy mode, application is top priority, etc...